# How to start on-screen-keyboard when installing windows

Tags: windows-7, command-line, installation

How do I start the on-screen-keyboard during the windows installation process? I need to install Windows 7 and I don't have keyboard, I only have a mouse.

Comment: Please edit your question and clarify. It is difficult to understand what you are trying to do, your question may be closed.

Comment: Are you asking how to start the on screen keyboard in windows?

Comment: I edited your edit to have proper grammar, if I was wrong you can roll back the change.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first phase of the install will not require the keyboard. You should be able to go mouse only all the way until it prompts you to enter a new username and password.

[image]

Once you get there click the button in the bottom left corner (highlighted in yellow in the above screen shot) that will bring up the "Ease of Access" menu

[image]

Check the box for "Type Without the keyboard". Once you click OK it will enable the On-Screen Keyboard

[image]

Comment: Great, great, great!!! Thank you Scott.. Man I wish we have all members like you :)

Answer (score -1):

For anyone who don't have some working keyboard buttons and who wants to type during first parts of installation, for example DISKPART commands. You just have right click on one of the listed command and  it will appear typed or coppied.